# Skin a dialog box

Tags: c++, skinning, dialog

I am writing a C++ application and I have a Login Box that's shown in a regular Dialog Box Frame.  I see that some people can SKIN the entire dialog box and makes it look really nice.  I was wondering if anyone can give me some pointers as to how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd need more details to give you a good answer.

The answer very much depends on which OS you're using and how you're programming your GUI (for example on Windows - plain Win32, MFC, ATL, Qt, Windows Forms, WPF etc etc).

If you're just using the Windows API here's a link to get you started.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/skinstyle.aspx

Beware: custom skinning dialog boxes can be a very large task if you want to customise the look of every control as you end up writing very complicated custom controls.

Alternatively do you just want to make sure that your dialogs appear with Windows XP visual style rather than pre-XP style? This will require changes to your application to use the new common controls and visual style. Note that this changes the behaviour of some Windows APIs and can potentially have side effects (see ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED).

Comment: My application is actually a background process.  All it has is a Login Dialog Box.  That's the only thing i need to Skin.  After the user login, everything goes to background process.  I am current using MFC.

Comment: To be even more precise,  I just want to have a Image that'll cover the entire login box.  Login button will also be an image.  Dialog Title and the Close button should be removed too.

Comment: Googling for "mfc skin dialog" finds some advice I've pasted below. I think you can expect that doing these changes is more than a few lines of extra code, especially if you want to change the look of the non-client area (title and close button).

Comment: From CodeProject:
You can make a picture the background of the dialog by drawing it in the dialog's OnPaint () handler. (OnDraw () doesn't work for dialog boxes.) Another possiblity is OnEraseBackground ().
MFC has a CBitmapButton class that you can use for pictures on the buttons.

Comment: Also interesting info and links at the bottom of this article: http://www6.conestogac.on.ca/~set/courses/year2/gui/mfctips.html